# CSS not reading correctly in Chrome - need webkit for width/color?

Tags: css, google-chrome, width, background-color

I have a web page where I am creating a legend for a map. It renders perfect in Edge, but only renders two of the items correctly in Chrome for whatever reason.

Basically, I have expanded the width property of the legend so the entire legend item name can be seen clearly and I have added a new legend item to describe the color orange.

I have attached the correct looking legend (rendered in edge) and the problem legend (rendered in Chrome). Chrome should be able to read width and background-color without using webkit as far as I know, so I'm not sure what the problem is.

[Good legend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZGWQ4.png)

[Bad legend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dqka.png)

Please note - it renders the green and gray legend items correctly, but won't render orange for whatever reason. The class "legend-color" has to be initialized with something so black is used before being overwritten with the appropriate color.

The classes in question (mainly ".legend-color orange" and "legend-item") in CSS:

```css
.legend-color {
  width: 30px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: black;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.legend-color.green {
  background-color: rgba(8, 107, 27, 0.70);
}

.legend-color.grey {
  background-color: rgba(105, 105, 105, 0.70);
}

.legend-color.orange {
  background-color: rgba(252, 140, 12, 0.70);
}

.legend-text {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding-top: 2px;
}

.legend-item {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 170px;
  margin: 5px;

The HTML that references above classes:
```

```html
 <div id="cip-states-map">
  <div id="cip-states-legend">
        <h1>Legend</h1>
        <div class="legend-item">
          <div class="legend-color green"></div>
          <p class="legend-text">Enrolled</p>
        </div>
        <div class="legend-item">
          <div class="legend-color grey"></div>
          <p class="legend-text">In Development</p>
        </div>
        <div class="legend-item">
          <div class="legend-color orange"></div>
          <p class="legend-text">Has &gt;1 Focal Area</p>
        </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: It works fine here (from your code snippet in my Chrome). Try doing right-click on the 'orange' div and choose "Inspect", then use the Dev Tools to see what styles Chrome thinks it should apply and where they are coming from.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Chrome 59. Does the issue occur if you open the page in an incognito tab?

Comment: Appreciate the help. I did a hard refresh and you're right...everything is coming up fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon running the code provided inside stackoverflow, Chrome is rendering as it should be. There might be a caching issue for you which can be resolved with a hard refresh (Shift+F5) or by opening the Inspector in Chrome and disabling the cache under the network tab.

You probably don't need to specify the black background colour in the .legend-color class either if it isn't being used.

Comment: Hm, you're right. Weird. I'm pretty new to CSS/HTML so knowing to try this next time something weird happens is a big help. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It's always good in Chrome to keep the Inspector open with the disable cache option selected. That way you can be sure that you are seeing the most recent version both javascript and stylesheets.